# Data Output in a report with multiple datasources

Tags: sql, arrays, sorting, ms-access, ms-access-2010

first of all, I would like to apologize, if this question is already answered, but I cannot find anything useful related to my problem by searching for it, as I do not know the exact name of the problem.

First of all, I have those tables:

Table A:

```
ID | Title | many more fields
------------------------------
1 | title1 | .... 
2 | title2 | ....
...
```

Table B:

```
ID | project_ID | Date B | many more fields
-------------------------------------------
1 | 1 | 01.01.2017
2 | 1 | 01.02.2017
3 | 1 | 01.03.2017
4 | 2 | 02.01.2017
5 | 1 | 01.05.2017
6 | 3 | 01.03.2017
...
```

Table C:

```
ID | project_ID | Date C | many more fields
-------------------------------------------
1 | 1 | 01.01.2017
2 | 2 | 03.04.2017
3 | 2 | 11.10.2017
4 | 3 | 05.01.2017
5 | 1 | 06.02.2017
6 | 2 | 07.08.2017
...
```

Table D:

```
ID | project_ID | Date D | many more fields
-------------------------------------------
1 | 1 | 02.02.2017
2 | 2 | 03.03.2017
3 | 3 | 11.11.2017
4 | 1 | 04.04.2017
5 | 1 | 06.06.2017
6 | 2 | 07.07.2017
...
```

My Target is a report that looks something like:

```
Title1
-------------------------------------------
Date B     | Date C     | Date D
01.01.2017 | 01.01.2017 | 03.03.2017
01.02.2017 | 06.02.2017 | 04.04.2017
01.03.2017 |            | 06.06.2017
01.05.2017 | 


Title2
-------------------------------------------
Date B     | Date C     | Date D
02.01.2017 | 03.04.2017 | 02.02.2017
           | 11.10.2017 | 07.07.2017
           | 07.08.2017

...
```

The best result was with the "Access Report Builder" where I get something like:

```
Date B     | Date C     | Date D     | Misc
01.09.2017 | 28.08.2017 | 24.08.2017 | Title 1
01.09.2017 | 28.08.2017 | 25.08.2017 | Title 1
01.09.2017 | 28.08.2017 | 26.08.2017 | Title 1
01.09.2017 | 29.08.2017 | 24.08.2017 | Title 1
01.09.2017 | 29.08.2017 | 25.08.2017 | Title 1
01.09.2017 | 29.08.2017 | 26.08.2017 | Title 1
```

But as you see it repeats dates which should not happen. Even with hiding duplicates it only hides them. Date D would still show duplicates.

Last week I even got something like this:

SQL:

```
SELECT
    P.ID,
    P.title,
    P_kov.ko_date AS dateKOV,
    CVAR(NULL) AS dateAP,
    CVAR(NULL) AS dateEP
FROM
    P
LEFT JOIN
    P_kov ON P.ID = P_kov.id_projekt

UNION

SELECT
    P.ID,
    P.title,
    CVAR(NULL) AS dateKOV,
    CVAR(NULL) AS dateAP,
    P_ep.ep_date AS dateEP
FROM
    P
LEFT JOIN
    P_ep ON P.ID = P_ep.id_projekt

UNION

SELECT
    P.ID,
    P.title,
    CVAR(NULL)  AS dateKOV,
    P_ap.ap_date AS dateAP,
    CVAR(NULL)  AS dateEP
FROM
    P
LEFT JOIN
    P_ap ON P.ID = P_ap.id_projekt;
```

Note: I Used CVAR cause it seems like a Date cannot be NULL

Results:

```
Date KOV   | Date AP    | Date EP    | title
01.09.2017 |            |            | Title 1
02.09.2017 |            |            | Title 1
           | 28.08.2017 |            | Title 1
           | 29.08.2017 |            | Title 1
           |            | 25.08.2017 | Title 1
           |            | 26.08.2017 | Title 1
```

But sadly the report prints every empty field as a new line. And my skills in VBA are not that good that I can figure out how to put the results in an array and put the "cleaned" values in the text fields.

TLDR: I need a SQL-Query which gets me to my desired Report or a way to handle multiple data sources in VBA with manipulating data fields

Comment: Why try to do this in a single report? You could just create a report based on TableA, and add subreports for TableB, TableC and TableD. That can generate the desired output, without having to write difficult SQL queries.

Comment: Hello Erik,
thatnks for the tipp - i tried it and after finding out how grouping of a report worked (the comment of codenovice helped also) your tipp with subreports worked like a charm - thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

no need for vba. Assuming your many more fields for B, C and D are the same build a query in query builder with all four table joining B-D onto A only by project. then use the groups in the report to group by project id with the title in the group header. You should be able to put the Date B, C, D headers in the detail section header and get what you want.

Comment: Hello codenovice31415,
I tried your suggestion again, but i gor the same result as I wrote under "The best result was with the "Access Report Builder" where I get something like:" - lots of "duplicate" entries which will be displayed (or left as "empty cell" if hidden. So i tried the solution of Erik von Asmith which worked, but only combined with your tipp of grouping the report.